# Apache benchmark test on nginx web server running slow with more requests

Tags: apache, nginx, benchmarking

I see some strange results while using apache benchmark with nginx. Please see details below -

```
terminal:~ directory$ ab -c 100 -n 10000 http://localhost/banner.jpg
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.2.0
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /banner.jpg
Document Length:        16697 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.224 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      169226562 bytes
HTML transferred:       167094858 bytes
Requests per second:    8170.40 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       12.239 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.122 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          135024.21 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

But when I increase the number of requests from 10K to 15K, then the time for test increases from 1.124 seconds to 6.760 seconds.

```
terminal:~ directory$ ab -c 100 -n 15000 http://localhost/banner.jpg
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 1500 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4500 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7500 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10500 requests
Completed 12000 requests
Completed 13500 requests
Completed 15000 requests
Finished 15000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.2.0
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /banner.jpg
Document Length:        16697 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   6.760 seconds
Complete requests:      15000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      254201718 bytes
HTML transferred:       250999689 bytes
Requests per second:    2218.92 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       45.067 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.451 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          36722.28 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Did anyone notice this issue? Is there any tool to analyze nginx or apache benchmark tool and see what is taking some much of time?

Comment: My first guess is that you're running out of available ports.

Comment: My second guess is that you're starting to use more swap than memory.

Comment: show /var/log/messages and free -m after a second test

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments. I found one more interesting thing. When I restarted my computer today morning and tried second test straightaway, then it just took 1.882 seconds. Meanwhile, I found an interesting article  - http://alwaysthecritic.typepad.com/atc/2012/05/apache-bench-ab-stalls-after-16000-requests-ephemeral-ports.html. Please read it. It talks about ephemeral ports issues. KARASZI István suggestion was important. I will also try to investigate further and update you all about my findings. Thank you.